# Capturing child_process spawnSync or execSync stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there an easy way of capturing `child_process` `spawnSync` or `execSync` stdout/stderr? I have seen other posts say a few years ago that it wasn't possible at the time since it was synchronous.

I have a problem where I need to capture another threads output so I can parse what is sent to stdout. The problem is, I haven't found anything past just using `spawn` and use the `stdout.on` events.

This causes issues since my program isn't meant to be asynchronous.

**Edit:**

The tool I have is called [eslint-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-watch). It adds functionality to eslint like file watching and specifies a default directory. The problem is in this discussion https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2831 we came to the conclusion that I needed to execute eslint as a binary and grab the help options from it.

After eslint returns its help options I parse them and funnel them into opinionator. So my wrapper has the same help context menu as eslint but also has my commands in there. Problem is grabbing the help is one of the first things I do so I can parse the commands from the terminal.

Comment: Note for people like me who just want to do a simple stdout capture: as of Node v4.3, you can use `capturedOutput = child_process.execSync("your_subprocess")`
More details in the doc of the current Node version: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options

Answer (score 6):

Things have changed since your edit.

execSync now returns stdout on completion.

```
//will return date() on *nix systems;
console.log(require("child_process").execSync(`date`).toString());

>>> Fri Jul 10 14:19:41 UTC 2020
```

Answer (score 3):

Referring to `require('child_process').spawnSync() or .exexSync()`, the Node API [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_synchronous_process_creation) state pretty clearly that:

> These methods are synchronous, meaning they WILL block the event loop, pausing execution of your code until the spawned process exits.
>
> Blocking calls like these are mostly useful for simplifying general purpose scripting tasks and for simplifying the loading/processing of application configuration at startup.

So, you're correct. It is not possible to process stdio events while running an external process synchronously because the Node event loop is halted until the external process completes.

You might consider capturing the processes `stdout` and/or `stderr` to one or more files using shell output redirection (i.e. using bash: `COMMAND 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.log`) which you would do by running your command in the bash shell.

The simplest way to do this from Node would be to:

**file:runner.sh**

```
#/bin/sh
PATH_TO_YOUR_COMMAND_HERE 1>command_stdout.txt 2>command_stderr.txt
```

**file:nodeprocess.js**

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync,
    args = ['/bin/sh', 'runner.sh'];

spawnSync(args); // Event Loop will wait here.

if(fs.existsSync('./command_stdout.txt')){
  // process standard output from your command here
}
if(fs.existsSync('./command_stderr.txt')){
  // process error output from your command here
}
```

Of course, you should do all the proper file system hygiene things, like writing your output files into `/tmp` and removing them after you're done with them, but I leave those things to your imagination.

I'm curious why you cannot use `.spawn()` or `.fork()` since, if a command can be run from the command line, there should be no reason it cannot be run asychronously from Node.

Comment: Mostly I asked this question to see what other ideas people had. But It seems to be a negative thing to ask. :S As stated here, I am not the only one with this kind of question https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/9265

Ideally I would like to use spawnSync() just because the tool I created is a wrapper for another command line tool. I had only recently converted my app over to using spawn(), but it ended up causing a callback/promise chain I want to avoid.

Comment: If you can provide describe what you're after, I might be able to offer further help.

Comment: I have adding additional information to my question. There might not be a way around this and I might have to make a callback but I wasn't sure if there was another way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly and would guess an anwser is of no interrest to poster anymore. However since I struggled with something similar here some example:

```
var karma = spawnSync("node",
    ["node_modules/karma/bin/karma", "start", "karma.conf.js", "--single-run"],
    {
        stdio: [null, process.stdout, process.stderr]
    }
);
if (karma.status != 0) {
    console.log(`Karma reported error(s) (${karma.status}). Build aborted\n`.red);
    process.exit(1);
} else {
    console.log(`Karma success\n`.green);
}
```

The above example starts Karma and performs the tests specified in the config file. What I want with this is to force perform a test when webpack is set to do a release build. The idea is that the build server cannot perform a release without testing first, even if the build is missconfigured.

This ment introducing the above block into the webpack.conf.js and blocking the executing thread until karma is done, meanwhile piping karmas stdout/err onto the console. Using spawnSync instead of spawn is only neccessary since once the thread returns from the webpack.conf.json Webpack immediately starts and potentially build the project with failing tests.

What is described in the original question sound like an asynchronous thing to me. Call the process and once stdout arrives add your additional output in an event handler.
If you still wan't to do it synchronously, the stdio array just takes streams. This means you could create a wrapper stream for stdout and tell the child-process to use that.

Comment: I appreciate the input. It's been a year since I posted this. I had to do something similar in my project. If I am remembering correctly when I tried to execute Eslint with spawnSync, I couldn't capture the output as it was printing to console. I ended up being forced to use spawn and process it as the results came in. It could be my lack of knowledge directly pertaining to stdout and stderr and how they work within nested processes.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm new to node-js comming from C/Java, so I don't know for sure but from reading other examples I think being able to set stdio for spawnSync is new and wasn't a thing when you posted your question.